# How do I calculate the average of multiple fields in a mongoDB document?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate, field, average

I have a collection with the following fields:

```
_id:612ff22c17286411a17252cf
WELL:"199-H4-15A"
TYPE:"E"
SYSTEM:"HX"
ID:"199-H4-15A_E_HX"
Jan-14:-168.8
Feb-14:-151
Mar-14:-164.1
Apr-14:-168.7
May-14:-172.6
Jun-14:-177.3
Jul-14:-177.6
Aug-14:-171.9
Sep-14:-138.9
Oct-14:-130.3
Nov-14:-163.8
Dec-14:-161.4
Jan-15:-168.7
Feb-15:-168.9
Mar-15:-168.6
Apr-15:-164.6
May-15:-141.7
Jun-15:-153.5
Jul-15:-163.7
Aug-15:-167.7
```

and I am trying to take the average of all of the month fields (e.g. all files like "Jan-14", "Feb-14" and so on). I was thinking of somehow pushing all of the month fields data into an array and then average the values but would like to avoid having to list all of the individual field names. Below is what I have so far.

```
[{$match: {
  'WELL': '199-H4-15A'
}}, {$group: {
  _id: null,
  MonthAverageFlows: {
    $push: {
          $isNumber: ['$all']
    }
  }
}}, {$unwind: '$MonthAverageFlows'}, {$group: {
  _id: null,
  average: {
    $avg: '$MonthAverageFlows.value'
  }
}}]
```

All that comes out is ```null``. Any and all help would be appreciated. The raw data is in csv form:

```
WELL, TYPE, SYSTEM, ID, JAN-14, FEB-14, . . .
"199-H4-15A", "E", "HX", "199-H4-15A_E_HX", -168.8, -151, . . .
```

Comment: What does a raw data/document look like?

Comment: csv for raw data. Each field in the document shown represents a column in the csv. The DB documents are represent the rows in the csv.

Comment: The truth is that you should modify the data before putting it in Mongo. Personally, I would add a `dates` prop. `{ _id: 123, system: "hx", etc.., dates: [{ date: "Jan-14", value: -168.8 }, { ...etc }, { ...etc }] }`. That would be a million times easier to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic values as field name is generally considered as anti-pattern and you should avoid that. You are likely to introduce unnecessary difficulty to composing and maintaining your queries.

Nevertheless, you can do the followings in an aggregation pipeline:

1. `$objectToArray` to convert your raw document into k-v tuples array
2. `$filter` the array to get contain the monthly data only
3. `$avg` to calculate the sum

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/jHpaApwNUFO) for your reference.

Comment: Thank you. I did find it much better to reformat that raw data an start with all of the dates and values under their own fields.